# How to decode the URL when navigating one route to another roue in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I want to navigate a page from one route another route with query parameters.

```
var name = "engine & machinery";

this.router.navigateByUrl('dashboard?isopen='+true+'&name='+name);
```

From this, route navigate to dashboard page but query parameters not coming properly.

Url comes like,

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard?isopen=true&name=engine%20&%20machinery=
```

Getting query parameters by the following code,

```
console.log("testt", this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('name'));
```

its return only the `"engine"`.

So, anyone help me for decoding the url and how to get the parameter value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the URL with special characters like these.

```
var name = encodeURIComponent("engine & machinery");
```

while creating the URL.

And in the receiving end, decode it using the `decodeURIComponent`

Something like this:

```
const encodedName = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('name')
const decodedName = decodeURIComponent(encodedName);
// This would yield `engine & machinery`
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its working fine. But the URL is not a readable format.Is there any method for this?

Comment: Yes, if you have a look at the answer carefully, you'll have to use `decodeURIComponent` method and pass the unreadible url through that to get the original values.